# Adding a drag icon to Focus+Context via Brushing Chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to adapt Mike Bostock's Focus+Context via Brushing chart at: bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 ‎ to include a drag icon on both vertical lines of the brush rectangle. These should appear once a selection is made and act as a visual cue to shrink or expand the selected/brushed area. I see the placement of the images being dynamic i.e. moving fluidly with the brushed area as opposed to an update after the brushed area is reset. What seems most reasonable to me would be to add an svg image to the context rectangle like so:

```
//original code
context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x brush")
  .call(brush)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .attr("y", -6)
  .attr("height", height2 + 7)

//additional code
 .append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "icon.png")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("opacity",1)
```

I've tried playing around with the x and y positioning of both images with no luck getting them to appear, but i conceptually see it working as

- y axis: height of context chart divided by 2
- x axis: each image respectively corresponding to the min and max x values of the brushed area

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that you append the images to the `g` element and not the `rect`s.

Answer (score 0):

Lars, thanks for the pointer which generally led me in the right direction although I ended up directly adapting from an example at https://engineering.emcien.com/2013/05/7-d3-advanced-brush-styling. That example is a bit more complex so i borrowed from a subset relevant to my purposes.

Steps i followed include

1.) Creating two images appended to the context g element and initializing their position somewhere that doesn't give the impression that the chart is brushed on loading {i put them halfway (vertically) and close together around the end of the context(horizontally)}.

```
var leftHandle = context.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "icon.gif")
  .attr("width", 11)
  .attr("height", 27)
  .attr("x",x2(data[data.length-6].date))
  .attr("y", (height2/2)-15);

var rightHandle = context.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "icon.gif")
  .attr("width", 11)
  .attr("height", 27)
  .attr("x",x2(data[data.length-1].date))
  .attr("y", (height2/2)-15);
```

2.) Within the brush function, i created a variable to hold brush.extent(), then tied the x attributes of the images to its min and max x values.

```
var ext = brush.extent();
  leftHandle.attr("x",x2(ext[0]));
  rightHandle.attr("x",x2(ext[1]));
```

One things i'm not completely satisfied with is that when i initially created the images after the brush rectangle, they sat on top of it, preventing me from being able to brush if i hovered over the images (which is the intuitive reaction desired). I ended up placing the images behind the rectangle which has a low opacity. Not the 100% accurate visual representation sought, but it works just fine.

Comment: Nowadays you can try adding the css class `pointer-events:none` to the images, which makes it transparent for interactions